# Xcode watch simulator core data file location

Tags: xcode, sqlite, core-data, watchkit, watchos-simulator

For debugging purposes, it would be very helpful if I could read the contents of the Xcode watch simulator's core data sql file. Can anyone tell me how to find this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The simulator files are located in `~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/{UUID}/`. You can search the `Devices` folder for files with the extension `.sqlite` to find all your databases. You can also find the UUID for a specific simulator in `device_set.plist` in `Devices`.